# How to build a ros node that uses sqlite3?

Tags: c++, sqlite, cmake, ros, catkin

I am trying to use sqlite3 in a ROS node. I think that ROS depends on sqlite3 so I already have the library on my system. The header file is in /usr/lib/. However, when I build my tests with catkin, I get linker errors against the functions in the sqlite3.h header. What do I need to do in my CMake to build against sqlite3?

I included relevant files, but I think the only one you might really need to see is the CMakeLists.txt.

I'm using ros melodic.

Linker errors:

```
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/cmake/3.15.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/sqlite_gtest.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/sqlite_gtest.dir/test/sqlite_test.cpp.o  -o /home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/devel/.private/tros_logging/lib/tros_logging/sqlite_gtest  -L/home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/build/tros_logging/gtest -Wl,-rpath,/home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/build/tros_logging/gtest:/home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/build/tros_logging/gtest/googlemock/gtest:/opt/ros/melodic/lib:/home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/devel/.private/tros_logging/lib gtest/googlemock/gtest/libgtest.so /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libroscpp.so -lboost_filesystem -lboost_signals /opt/ros/melodic/lib/librosconsole.so /opt/ros/melodic/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so /opt/ros/melodic/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so -llog4cxx -lboost_regex /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so /opt/ros/melodic/lib/librostime.so /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libcpp_common.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so.0.4 -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono -lboost_date_time -lboost_atomic -lpthread /home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/devel/.private/tros_logging/lib/libtros_logging.so -lpthread 
/home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/devel/.private/tros_logging/lib/libtros_logging.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_step'
/home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/devel/.private/tros_logging/lib/libtros_logging.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
/home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/devel/.private/tros_logging/lib/libtros_logging.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_prepare_v2'
/home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/devel/.private/tros_logging/lib/libtros_logging.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_finalize'
/home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/devel/.private/tros_logging/lib/libtros_logging.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_bind_text'
/home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/devel/.private/tros_logging/lib/libtros_logging.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_bind_int64'
/home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/devel/.private/tros_logging/lib/libtros_logging.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
/home/alexmussell/catkin_ws/devel/.private/tros_logging/lib/libtros_logging.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_errmsg'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(tros_logging)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rostest
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS 
    include
  LIBRARIES 
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS 
    roscpp
)


set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS
  src/sqlite_logging_database.cpp
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS})


#############
## Testing ##
#############

catkin_add_gtest(sqlite_gtest 
  test/sqlite_test.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(sqlite_gtest
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
)
```

Where I import the header (sqlite_logging_database.h)

```
#pragma once

#include "tros_logging/logging_database.h"
#include <sqlite3.h>

namespace tros_logging
{
    class SQLiteLoggingDatabase : public LoggingDatabase
    {
        public:

            SQLiteLoggingDatabase(std::string sqlite_database_file);
            ~SQLiteLoggingDatabase();

            bool logEvent(Event event);
            bool logError(Error error);
            bool logTiming(Timing timing);
            bool logMetric(Metric metric);
            Event loadEvent(std::string uuid);
            Error loadError(std::string uuid);
            Timing loadTiming(std::string uuid);
            Metric loadMetric(std::string uuid);

        private:
            sqlite3* db_connection;
            void checkError(int error_code);
    };

    class SQLiteError : public std::runtime_error
    {
        public:
            explicit SQLiteError(std::string what) : std::runtime_error(what)
            {

            }
    };
}
```

CPP File that implements my code (sqlite_logging_database.cpp)

```
#include "tros_logging/sqlite_logging_database.h"
#include <ros/ros.h>

namespace tros_logging
{
    SQLiteLoggingDatabase::SQLiteLoggingDatabase(std::string sqlite_database_file)
    {
        int err = 0;
        err = sqlite3_open(sqlite_database_file.c_str(), &(this->db_connection));
        if(err)
        {
            ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Error opening sqlite database file: " << sqlite_database_file << " : " << sqlite3_errmsg(this->db_connection));            
        }
    }

    SQLiteLoggingDatabase::~SQLiteLoggingDatabase()
    {
        sqlite3_close(this->db_connection);
    }

    bool SQLiteLoggingDatabase::logEvent(Event event)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt * stmt;
        std::string sql = "INSERT INTO events (uuid,  type, parent_event_uuid, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try
        {
            int err = sqlite3_prepare_v2(this->db_connection, sql.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL);
            this->checkError(err);
            err = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, event.uuid.c_str(), event.uuid.length(), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            this->checkError(err);
            err = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, event.type.c_str(), event.type.length(), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            this->checkError(err);
            err = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, event.parent_uuid.c_str(), event.parent_uuid.length(), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            this->checkError(err);
            err = sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, 4, event.timestamp.toNSec());
            this->checkError(err);
            err = sqlite3_step(stmt);
            this->checkError(err);
            err = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
            this->checkError(err);
        }
        catch(const SQLiteError e)
        {
            ROS_ERROR_STREAM(e.what() << '\n');
        }
    }

    bool SQLiteLoggingDatabase::logError(Error error)
    {

    }

    bool SQLiteLoggingDatabase::logTiming(Timing timing)
    {

    }

    bool SQLiteLoggingDatabase::logMetric(Metric metric)
    {

    }

    Event SQLiteLoggingDatabase::loadEvent(std::string uuid)
    {

    }

    Error SQLiteLoggingDatabase::loadError(std::string uuid)
    {

    }

    Timing SQLiteLoggingDatabase::loadTiming(std::string uuid)
    {

    }

    Metric SQLiteLoggingDatabase::loadMetric(std::string uuid)
    {

    }

    void SQLiteLoggingDatabase::checkError(int error_code)
    {
        if(error_code)
        {
            std::string err_msg = sqlite3_errmsg(this->db_connection);
            ROS_ERROR_STREAM("SQLITE ERROR: " << err_msg);
            throw SQLiteError(err_msg);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "*I get linker errors against the functions in the sqlite3.h header*"... Can you please post the **specific** errors you are seeing?

Comment: Done. I updated the post with them.

Comment: I'm not a cmake/linux person, but. I don't see the likes of sqlite3.os or the sqlite3.cpp like files on your build line. Here I add sqlite3.lib, that I've built, to my lib list when using sqlite3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your library depends on SQLite3, as the error messages and your file naming suggest, you should import this package into CMake using [`find_package(SQLite3)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindSQLite3.html). It doesn't appear (based on the error output) that the SQLite3 library was linked via `catkin_LIBRARIES`, so you may have to do this manually:

```
... 

# Tell CMake to locate the SQLite3 package on your machine.
find_package(SQLite3 REQUIRED)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS})

# Link the SQLite3 imported target to your own library.
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC SQLite::SQLite3)

...
```